# What is end-to-end service deployment in the area of cloud computing

Tags: service, cloud, end-to-end

I faced this term *end-to-end service deployment* what does it means in the area of cloud computing?

Answer (score 1):

It may simply mean that all the elements of the service are deployed in the cloud - for example for a typical 3 tier web service, the web server, application servers and database would all be hosted on nodes in a 'cloud' offering.

It could also be taking about the actual action of deploying the service in the cloud - for example the above 3 tier web service might have a scripted deployment which allows you deploy the entire service end to send with a 'one button' click. Take a look at 'Puppet' (https://puppetlabs.com) or Amazon Cloud formation(http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) for some examples.